# How to manage Push Notification from Web API to Android App with Firebase?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

How to manage Push Notification from Web API to Android App using Firebase?

I have a web application,and want a Push Notification, while any changes on web application database then it will show a notification to my android app.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Check this link https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/89731/how-to-implement-fcm-in-xamarin-forms I followed this for my app and worked perfectly!